# Can I show my website only in specific country including for search engine users?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, search-engines, geotargeting, block

How can I show a certain website only in specific country? This includes not showing on search engines outside of that certain country?

Its not about blocking the access, but not showing / visible outside of it.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the difference between "not showing" and "blocking."  Wouldn't you want to block access from outside the country and show an error message as part of the solution?

Comment: in my understanding, "blocking" means people can still search our website (in the search engine) but cant access it... however what we intended to do is to not be "visible in the search engine" and we will also definitely block the access

Comment: Ah, you mean that you don't want to disallow it in robots.txt

Comment: A point to consider: presumably, you'd be doing some sort of IP level blocking to prevent extra-national traffic to your site. If you're not in the US, that would likely include the spiders for most major search engines.

Comment: From experience, I would say that blocking whole countries from visiting a website is generally more trouble than its worth. And unless you have a compelling reason to do so, it would be more appropriate to ensure the content and services are clearly marked as being solely targeted at your domestic audience.

Answer (score 1):

I often see messages that say this site is not available in your region, as far as I am aware this is done using the octets within your IP address to determine your location.   So it can be done but only at the IP level and not by search engine.

Comment: There are additional matters about ISP use and access mode - it can be done via proxies and VPN services. It greatly complicates measures based on IP level.